# "Battery not present" on Toshiba Satellite L500D

Tags: 12.04, battery

I bought a new battery for my laptop a week ago and it worked fine up until last night when it wouldn't boot up. I plugged in the power lead and it booted but upon booting the battery status indicator shows "not present" even though it most definitely is.

`dmesg | grep battery`

```
[    0.412399] ACPI: Deprecated procfs I/F for battery is loaded, please retry with CONFIG_ACPI_PROCFS_POWER cleared
[    0.412411] ACPI: Battery Slot [BAT1] (battery present)
[    0.660147] [Firmware Bug]: battery: (dis)charge rate invalid.
[    0.660207] ACPI: Battery Slot [BAT1] (battery present)
```

---

`cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT1/info`

```
present:                 yes
design capacity:         4400 mAh
last full capacity:      3497 mAh
battery technology:      rechargeable
design voltage:          10800 mV
design capacity warning: 340 mAh
design capacity low:     102 mAh
cycle count:          0
capacity granularity 1:  264 mAh
capacity granularity 2:  3780 mAh
model number:            
serial number:           41167
battery type:            Li-Ion
OEM info:                TOSHIBA
```

---

`cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT1/state`

```
present:                 yes
capacity state:          ok
charging state:          charging
present rate:            2 mA
remaining capacity:      0 mAh
present voltage:         10447 mV
```

So I'm a little confused as some things are telling me its there and charging and others are not. Either way the battery is no longer holding charge because if I pull the power lead it turns off immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart your laptop with different OSes. If Windows or Mac OS does not find any batteries, it is a hardware problem - with your battery, your battery "jack" (the part that takes power from the battery and feed it to the computer), or the connection. Reinsert your battery. If not working, request a warranty.

Comment: I re-installed Windows 7 in some spare space and updated all the drivers but still no joy. I've logged a fault with the store I purchased it from so I can get a replacement - just seemed odd that it failed so quickly.