# battery (not present) - but it is

Tags: battery

I am having a Acer Aspire 4820T. I just installed Ubuntu 12.04. All is good but the battery shows as not present even though it is. And I don't have the power cable attached.

Have tried the commands in this post :

["Battery not present" on Toshiba Satellite L500D](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150708/battery-not-present-on-toshiba-satellite-l500d)

But I get:

```
cat: /proc/acpi/battery/BAT1/state: No such file or directory
```

and

```
jim@ubuntu:/proc$ dmesg | grep battery
[    1.525162] ACPI: Battery Slot [BAT1] (battery present)
```

So it seems to know it is present, but the directory `/proc/acpi/battery` doesn't exist:

```
jim@ubuntu:/proc/acpi$ ls
button  event  wakeup
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.14 doesn't exist. Did you mean 12.04 or 12.10? Please edit your question as this might be relevant.

Comment: 12.04 - edited, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have one too and it gives me a lot of issues(internet, screen...). What you can try is to just keep reinstalling ubuntu until it works.